# Interview: How to handle SQL NOT NULL constraint on the code end

Tags: sql

I was recently asked this question in an interview an I'm having trouble formulating the question well enough to find an answer via search engine.

If my SQL database has a NOT NULL constraint placed on the "name" column, how would I be able to create that row, filling it with other data, without tripping the "name" NOT NULL constraint, assuming that you don't have the proper data to insert into the "name" field?

My off the cuff response was to insert an empty string into the "name" field, but I feel like that's too hacky. Does anyone know the proper response?

Comment: You would use a `DEFAULT` value.

Comment: why bypass the constraint? in my opinion either your data is wrong or the constraint. if you bypass constraints, you can&#39;t assure some data quality inside the db. so i would say the scenario where a table could not be changed even if tge constraint is wrong is a huge technical debt which should be solved instead.

Comment: That's a great comment and that's really what I should have responded. However, the challenge was presented regardless and I was being tested on my knowledge of SQL. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: On the code end? I.e. without altering the table structure?

Comment: Correct. However, an answer has already been given below.

Comment: ok i guess then i will add it as a regular answer because it&#39;s an alternaive "solution" to the already existing answers

Comment: Yea, my answer is clearly the best answer. Don't know why Gordon's is marked as correct when it violates the constraints of the question asked... Snaps is an interesting answer as well... but as this is an interview question, the interviewer is probably looking for a SQL specific answer rather that data quality assessment

Comment: Ok guys, I'm marking james5' answer correct since it actually does not require the table to be altered. However, I'm a new developer and it becomes frustrating for me to post questions when I have to pick a favorite. I appreciate the help from all of you. I'm just here to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually a best practice to insert a dummy value such as a -1 that you can easily replace later. A blank string can be more problematic in some cases. To do this you would either use a CASE WHEN statement, or ideally, an ISNULL() function which would look like this `ISNULL([ColName], -1)`  ISNULL is probably the answer they were looking for. That would insert the data if you have it and then if it's null, it would insert a -1.

As Gordon commented, you could also use a DEFAULT value when creating the table. In my answer above, I am assuming you're working with a table that had already been created - meaning you couldn't do that without altering the table.

Comment: Correct, the question was how to handle the case without changing the table.

Comment: @MBaka then yea Gordon's answer is wrong because you have to alter the table for that to work. The correct answer would be "wrap the [Name] column with ISNULL([Name], -1) in the INSERT statement. You could also use a trigger or CASE statement, but that would be unnecessarily complicated when a simple ISNULL function would allow you to insert the row."

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways that I can think of for not having to insert `name` if it is `NULL`.  By far the simpler is to define a default value:

```
alter table t alter column name varchar(255) not null default '<no name>';
```

The alternative is to use a trigger, but that is much more cumbersome.

If I were asking a similar question, this is the answer that I would want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gordon! This is probably what I'm looking for and I would have marked it correct but james5 had a lengthier response.

Comment: @MBaka . . . I don't think James's response is correct.

Comment: Oh bs dude, altering the table is unnecessarily complicated and can cause issues with related sprocs... a simple isnull fuction is clearly the less risky option. If I asked this in an interview, I'd definitely prefer someone who says ISNULL over DEFAULT. No way is this a better answer... obviously you should say both, but ISNULL is a requirement for the answer, DEFUALT is just bonus point in my book.

Comment: "how would I be able to create that row, filling it with other data".  I interpret this as "the users don't want to consider the `name` column at all".

Answer (score 0):

Why bypass the constraint?

In my opinion either your data is wrong or the constraint.

If you bypass constraints, you can't assure some data quality inside the db.

So, i would say the scenario where a table could not be changed even if the constraint is wrong is a huge technical debt which should be solved instead.

Comment: Excellent comment and that's really what I should have responded. However, the challenge was presented regardless and I was being tested on my knowledge of SQL.

Comment: @MBaka alright but if you think that is what you should respond then i guess it's a regular answer to the question. sql skills are still involved in the answer.